# unable to print array to table via vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

could anyone pls tell me why this table isn't printing the result? it appears that axios is pulling the data ok and printing to console.log, but the view is not outputting in the table.

```
<table id="app">
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user in users">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            users: []
        },
        methods: {
            getAllUsers: function(){
                axios.get("http://example.net/users/process.php?action=read").then(function(response){
                    if(response.data.error){
                        app.errorMsg = response.data.message;
                    }
                    else{
                        app.users = response.data.users;
                        console.log(app.users);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.getAllUsers();
        }
    })
</script>
```

thx so much guys for your time!

Comment: Check your console. It should show some errors from vuejs.

Comment: Are you defining `app` anywhere? If not then `app` will just be referring to the element with the id `app`, which is not what you want. I suggest using an arrow function for the `then` callback so that you can use `this.users` instead.

Answer (score 2):

wow you guys are fast! @skirtle thank you ! i made the modification by using the arrow and then using this.users and it worked!

```
                getAllUsers: function(){
                    axios.get("http://example.net/users/process.php?action=read").then(response => {
                        if(response.data.error){
                            this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
                        }
                        else{
                            this.users = response.data.users;
                            console.log(this.users);
                        }
                    });
                }
```